# how to write a c++ code for javascript "this.path.split('"/');"

Tags: javascript, c++, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I have problem in making a adobe plugin to get the path of the open document, when i just tried javascript tool to insert a tool box in Adobe, In that i managed to get the path using the script below.

```
  var path = this.path.split('"/');
```

I want know how to get the path in c++ Like this or just how to use the same code type in c++. 
Please help me with this Thank you.

Comment: You could try the Boost FileSystem Library. Other than having a current_path function, it also provides portable path parsing which would otherwise be very hard to get right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using plain c++, you can use the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  vector<string> v;
  string s = "/path/to/foo/bar";
  istringstream iss(s);
  while (!iss.eof())
  {
    string x;
    getline(iss, x, '/');
    v.push_back(x);
  }

  for (vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/, section **iostreams and getline()** modified to use a vector.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to tokenize path variable. If so have a look on

[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sargi Eran, just want to get the path of the current document using c++.